# How can I strip double quotes and braces from my strings before insert in Rails4?

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-4, strip

I am parsing values from xml and saving them to variables.   I was able to strip all but the braces and double quotes from the string.  The value displays like this on the page: ["MPEG Video"].

Here is an exampled of the parse saving it to a variable:

```
@video_format = REXML::XPath.each(media_parse_doc, "//track[@type='Video']/Format/text()") { |element| element }
```

I tried using .ts like this:

```
@video_format = (REXML::XPath.each(media_parse_doc, "//track[@type='Video']/Format/text()") { |element| element } ).ts('[]"','')
```

but it did not work.  I saw some examples telling to you gsub and I looked at the api dock for gsub but I am not understanding the thought logic in the examples to be able to apply it correctly to my own case.   Here is one of the examples:

```
"foobar".gsub(/^./, "")  # => "oobar"
```

I understand it is removing te first character but I don't know how to set it up to remove " and [.
Why the /^?   Is that ascii for something?   Can someone please show me the correct syntax to remove the double quotes and braces from my varialbes and explain the logic process so I can better understand to use on my own in the future?
Thank you for the help!

Comment: could you post an input along with expected output?

Comment: **I am parsing values from xml and saving them to variables.**  Then why didn't you post a small example of your xml and the string you want to produce from the xml?  And you are still making the same mistakes that you've posted in your last ten questions.  Why don't you actually try reading the answers to your questions some time?

Comment: What is `ts`?  The rails docs reveal no such method. And the ruby String and Array docs do not list a method named ts.  If you actually mean String#tr, `puts '--->["hello"]<----'.tr('[]"', '') => `--->hello<----`  But then REXML#each doesn't return a String does it?  You would know that if you actually read the answers to all the other questions you've posted.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to understand regular expressions, check out http://rubular.com/.

`"foobar".gsub(/^./, "")  # => "oobar"` that particular example will substitue the first letter of the string with "" (ie, nothing). The reason is that the `^` says "pin the match to the beginning of the string", and the `.` says "match any character" - so, it'll match any character at the beginning of the string. The encosing `/` characters are just the standard delimiters for a regular expression - so it's only the `^.` that you need to figure out.

To replace double quotes: `'fo"o"bar'.gsub(/"/, "")  # => "foobar"`

To replace left square bracket: `'fo[o[bar'.gsub(/\[/, "")  # => "foobar"` (because square brackets are a special character in regex, you have to prefix them with a `\` when you want to use them as a 'normal' character.

to replace all quotes and square brackers in one:  `'fo[o"[b]"ar'.gsub(/("|\[|\])/, "")  # => "foobar"`

(the parenthesis indicate a group, and the pipes `|` indicate 'or'. So, `("|\[|\])` means "match any of the things in this group: a quote, or a left square bracket, or a right square bracket".

But really what you should do is do a good intro tutorial to regular expressions and start from the basics. Once you understand that, it shouldn't be too hard to start composing simple regular expressions of your own.

If you're on a mac, this app is very useful for writing your own regex's: http://krillapps.com/patterns/